# Как отцентровать span по вертикали?

Tags: html, css

```css
body{
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
 background: #f5f5f5;
 font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
}
header{
 text-align: center;
 font-weight: 100;
 font-size: 100px;
 font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
 color: #ecdbdb;
}
.body-main{
 height: 67vmin;
 width: 90vmin;
 margin: auto;
}
.input{
 height: 10vmin;
 background: #ffffff;
 border: 1px solid #e6e6e6;
 width: auto;
}
input[name="input_name"]::-webkit-input-placeholder {
    color: #e0e0e0;
    font-weight: 300;
    font-size: 18px;
    font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
    font-style: italic;
    height: 5em;
}
ul{
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
}
li{
 height: 10vmin;
 list-style-type: none;
 border-bottom: 1px solid #e6e6e6;
 border-left: 1px solid #e6e6e6;
 border-right: 1px solid #e6e6e6;
    background: #ffffff;
    color: #666666;
    padding: 0.18em 0;
    line-height: 3vmin;
    padding: 1% 0;
}
.check__box{
 position: absolute;
 background-image: url('empty.svg'); 
 width: 2.25em;
 height: 2.25em;
 margin-left: 0em;
 line-height: 0.8em;
 text-decoration: line-through;
}
.namet{
 padding-left: 3em;
 margin-top: 0.15em;
}
.check__input:checked + .check__box{
 background-image: url('compl.svg'); 
}
.delete{
 position: relative;
 background: transparent;
 background-image: url('close.png'); 
 width: 1.5em;
 height: 1.5em;
 background-repeat : no-repeat;
 border:none;
 margin-top: -1.3vw;
 margin-right: 1vw;
 margin-bottom: auto;
 display: flex;
 margin-left: auto;
 display:none;
}
li:hover{
 background: #fafafa;
 cursor: pointer;
}
li:hover .delete{
    display:block;
}
.empty{
 height: 10vmin;
 list-style-type: none;
 border-left: 1px solid #e6e6e6;
 border-right: 1px solid #e6e6e6;
    background: #ffffff;
    color: #666666;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #e6e6e6;
}
.button__input{
 float: left;
 background: transparent;
 background-image: url('select-all.png'); 
 width: 24px;
 height: 12px;
 border: none;
 margin: 0.5vw;
 /*margin-top: 1.5vw;*/
}
.input__name{
 /*margin-top: 1.5vw;*/
 width: 92%;
 margin-top: 0.3vw;
 border: none;
}
.input{
 clear:both; 
 text-align:left;
}
input[type=checkbox]:checked  + span + .namet{
 text-decoration: line-through;
 color: #d8d8d8;
}
.container{
 white-space:nowrap;
 background: #ffffff;
 color: #666666;
 font-size: 15px;
 margin-bottom: auto;
 margin-top: auto;
 padding: 0.15vw
}
input[type="radio"]{
 display: none;
}
.button_1{
 padding-top: 0.3vw;
 padding-bottom: 0.3vw;
 padding-left: 1vw;
 padding-right: 1vw;
}
.button_2{
 padding-top: 0.3vw;
 padding-bottom: 0.3vw;
 padding-left: 1vw;
 padding-right: 1vw;
}
.button_3{
 padding-top: 0.3vw;
 padding-bottom: 0.3vw;
 padding-left: 1vw;
 padding-right: 1vw;
}
.container{
 display: flex;
    align-items: center; 
 border-left: 1px solid #e6e6e6;
 border-right: 1px solid #e6e6e6;
 padding: 13px;
}
.clear{
 margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: 0;
    padding-right: 0.7vw;
}
.items-left{
 margin-left: 0;
    margin-right: auto;
    padding-left: 0.7vw;
}
.buttons input:checked + span {
 border: 1px solid #ececec;
 padding: 5px;
 border-radius: 4px;
}
.down_1{
 height: 1.9vw;
 width: 89vmin;
 margin: auto;
}
.down_2{
 background: #fff;
 height: 0.3vw;
 width: 88vmin;
 margin: auto;
 z-index: -1;
 position: relative;
}
.down_3{
 background: #fff;
 height: 0.4vw;
 width: 87vmin;
 margin: auto;
 z-index: -2;
 position: relative;
}
.el{
 padding: 1.5em 0;
}
.check__box {
  transform: translate(0, -50%)
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <title>Todos</title>
 <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:100,300,400&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
</head>
<body>
 <div class="main">



  <header>
   todos
  </header>



  <div class="body-main">

   <div class="input">
    <div class="el">
     <button class="button__input"></button>
     <input type="text" name="input_name" class="input__name" placeholder="What needs to be done?">
    </div>
    
   </div>

   <ul>
    <label class="check option">
     <li>
      <div class="html">

        <input class="check__input" type="checkbox">

        <span class="check__box"></span>

        <div class="namet">
         HTML
        </div>
       
        <div class="my">
         <button type="button" class="delete"></button>
        </div>

      </div> 
     </li>
    </label>
    

    <label class="check option">
     <li>
      <input class="check__input" type="checkbox" name="" checked="">

      <span class="check__box"></span>

      <div class="namet">
       CSS
      </div>

      <div class="my">
       <button type="button" class="delete"></button>
      </div>

     </li>
    </label>
    

    <label class="check option">
     <li>
      <input class="check__input" type="checkbox" name="">

      <span class="check__box"></span>

      <div class="namet">
       JS
      </div>

      <div class="my">
       <button type="button" class="delete"></button>
      </div>

     </li>
    </label>
    

    <label class="check option">
     <li>
      <input class="check__input" type="checkbox" name="">

      <span class="check__box"></span>

      <div class="namet">
       JS tools
      </div>

      <div class="my">
       <button type="button" class="delete"></button>
      </div>

     </li>
    </label>
    

    <div class="empty">
    </div>
   </ul>


   <footer>
    <div class="container">
     
    <div class="items-left">
     3 items left
    </div>



     <div class="buttons">
     <label class="button_1">
        <input type="radio" name="button_footer" checked="checked">
        <span class="button_footer">All</span>
       </label>
       <label class="button_2">
        <input type="radio" name="button_footer">
        <span class="button_footer">Active</span>
       </label>
       <label class="button_3">
        <input type="radio" name="button_footer">
        <span class="button_footer">Completed</span>
       </label>
    </div>



    <div class="clear">
     clear completed
    </div>

    </div>

   </footer>
  </div>

  <div class="down_1">
  </div>

  <div class="down_2">
  </div>

  <div class="down_3">
  </div>





  




 </div>
</body>
</html>
```

В span лежит svg иконка. Я делал margin-top отступы через vw. Но на разных разрешениях все выглядит по-разному. Также я гуглил как центровать div. Заворачивал это в div, но все равно не работало.
https://danila-barsik1337.github.io/hw.github.io/

Answer (score 0):

Вам надо изучить,например,FlexBox если вам нужна адаптивная верстка, вот хорошая [статья](https://medium.com/@stasonmars/%D0%B2%D0%B5%CC%88%D1%80%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BA%D0%B0-%D0%BD%D0%B0-flexbox-%D0%B2-css-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B8%CC%86-%D1%81%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BA-e26662cf87e0) на эту тему.

И также вам не мешало бы почитать об HTML разметке . Ничего не зависит от того в какой  тег вы что оборачиваете, но оборачивать в `<li>` что-то кроме текста - неправильно.Этот тег является элементом нумерованного списка `<ol>` или не нумерованного  `<ul>`.

Что на счет центрирования вы могли бы это сделать так c помощью flexbox:

```css
body {
  display: flex;
  position: absolute;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.html {
  background: lightcoral;
}
```

```html
<html lang="ru">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">

</head>

<body>
  <div class="html">

    <input class="check__input" type="checkbox">

    <span class="check__box">span</span>

    <div class="namet">
      HTML
    </div>
    <button type="button" class="delete"></button>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

В вашем примере надо было использовать свойства top right left с  единицами измерения относительно окна браузера в `%` либо `vw` `vh` :

```css
.html {
  background: tomato;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translate(0, -50%)
}
```

```html
<html lang="ru">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">

</head>

<body>
  <div class="html">

    <input class="check__input" type="checkbox">

    <span class="check__box">span</span>

    <div class="namet">
      HTML
    </div>
    <button type="button" class="delete"></button>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

А также мне совсем не понятно чего вы хотите добиться, приводите более конкретные примеры, например, изображения.

P.S Вставляйте код в вопрос с помощью этой кнопки:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

так всем будет удобнее...